# Create a jquery function to call another preexisting function with custom variables

Tags: jquery, function

I have this function

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#slider").carouFredSel({

        items: {
            visible: 1,
            width: "auto"
        },
        auto: false,
        scroll: {
            fx: "fade",
            duration: "1500"
        },
        prev: {
            button: ".prev",
            key: "left"
        },
        next: {
            button: ".next",
            key: "right"
        }
    });

    var ratio = 1;
        $(window).resize(function() {
        var s = $("#slider");
        s.add( s.parent() ).height( s.children().first().height() * ratio )
    });

    $("#slider").trigger("updateSizes");

});
```

I have changed the default values to customize my slider.  I am using a navigation menu that calls in an HTML page, like so.

```
$("#graphic").click(function() {
        $("#slider").fadeOut( 1000, function() {
            $("#slider").load("graphic.html", function() {
                $("#slider").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    $("#slider").carouFredSel();
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

My problem is, when I recall the .carouFredSel();, I am getting it's default settings.  What I want to do is be able to create a function .mySlider() that reads the above function, with it's custom variables.

Does any of this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be about creating another function, but regarding the problem you are facing, Why don't you try storing the settings in a variable and use it at both places where you call .carouFredSel(). Below is what I mean:

```
var settings={

    items: {
        visible: 1,
        width: "auto"
    },
    auto: false,
    scroll: {
        fx: "fade",
        duration: "1500"
    },
    prev: {
        button: ".prev",
        key: "left"
    },
    next: {
        button: ".next",
        key: "right"
    }
}
```

And in the $(winodw).load() use as below:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$("#slider").carouFredSel(settings); //continue rest....
```

And also in the $("#graphic").click() function use the settings variable as below:

```
$("#graphic").click(function() {
    $("#slider").fadeOut( 1000, function() {
        $("#slider").load("graphic.html", function() {
            $("#slider").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $("#slider").carouFredSel(settings);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Just make sure settings variable's scope is fine so that you can access it at both places.

Comment: This worked, but my window resize won't work correctly... do you know why?

Comment: @Ryan if you can provide the link where you have this code running, i can take a look and get a clear picture of the window re-size problem.

Comment: ok, in the page the images are changing fine, do you want the images to get re-sized or what ? Try changing the var ratio = 1 to something else like 2, 3 etc. and see if size changes.

Comment: The images are supposed to have a 100% width, with an automatic height.

Comment: Are you not getting 100% width images ? Its showing 100% width in my browser (chrome). Also inspected the applied styles on the images, it's properly set to width:100% and height:auto. If you have recently changed the CSS, and not able to see the changes  try clearing the browser cache.

Comment: Go to the design page, then resize your window.  it won't keep it's proportions.

Comment: within the carousel settings, under items, the width is set to "auto", when you leave the main page, the width setting is no longer respected and defaults back to "null" the default...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6626/discussion-between-itypist-and-ryan)